# Modal MessageBox in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, messagebox

I'm trying to show a standard MessageBox as a modal window in my application, but it ends up as non modal.
In the first call, in the code below I'm showing a standard MessageBox which is shown modal, as it should. In the second call, it isn't shown as modal, even if I grab the main window dispatcher.

```
Dispatcher disp = Application.Current.MainWindow.Dispatcher;
//First call, shown MODAL
if (this.messageService.ShowYesNo("Do you want to update the Word document, this will regenerate inspectiondata for document", "") == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
{
    using (new WaitCursor())
    {
        _eventAggregator.GetEvent<ProgressBarRequestShow>().Publish("");
        worker = new BackgroundWorker();

        worker.DoWork += delegate(object s, DoWorkEventArgs args)
        {
            AITUpdateProgressDelegate update = new AITUpdateProgressDelegate(UpdateProgress);
            this.docService.UpdateWorddocument(this.docService.GetCurrentDocumentFilePath, update);
        };

        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += delegate(object s, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs args)
        {
            try
            {
                // Second call NOT MODAL
                disp.Invoke((Action)delegate()
                {
                    this.messageService.ShowInformation("Document generated, choose Open in Word in main toolbar to show document", "");
                });
                _eventAggregator.GetEvent<ProgressBarRequestHide>().Publish("");
            }
            finally
            {
            }
        };
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: why don't you use WPF Window to make custom messagebox?

Comment: I need to study the documentation a little bit more, a information messagebox is not modal by default, one needs to set owner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/arik/archive/2011/05/26/a-customizable-wpf-messagebox.aspx) looks like what you are looking for. The call for the message box includes an 'owner' parameter. I have used a similar concept in code that i have done before and has showed the windows as modal. Sample code can also be downloaded from the link.

Comment: Hi! Unfortunately the link is dead. Are you able to edit your answer with an example? (I know the answer is old, but it still comes up as top result on search engines for "wpf modal messagebox".)

Comment: The broken link was an blog article from Arik Poznanski and most likely the same content could currently be found at [codeproject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/201894/A-Customizable-WPF-MessageBox)